# Invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double') objective-c issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double') objective-c issue

```
-(double)performOperationWith:(double *)operand1 
                         And:(double *)operand2 {

    double result = 0.0;

    result = operand1 + operand2;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: 'm an Android programmer, I wanted to learn iOS. I forgot about the pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're pointers, so you should dereference them:

```
result = *operand1 + *operand2;
```

Or change the function parameters:

```
-(double)performOperationWith:(double )operand1 And:(double )operand2 {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `*`:

```
-(double)performOperationWith:(double)operand1  And:(double)operand2 {
    double result = 0.0;
    result = operand1 + operand2;
    return result;
}
```